# DB2 throughput when PaaS is offline?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I'm curious why there are a number of statements per hour when the PaaS is offline and nothing is actually accessing the Cloud DB2 database? Does that mean anything below 120/min or 250k/min rows read should be subtracted to get the real value?

[db2 throughput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaZKK.png)

Comment: Are you using Db2 on Cloud Lite plan? Db2 on Cloud Lite plan runs on a multi-tenant system. Other users might be accessing the system.

Comment: Also, the performance monitor queries that populate tables from which your throughput graphs are generated count as well.